# CentOS RPM: Find repo with older version of the lib

Tags: rpm, repository

I need to find older version of the lib: `cairo-1.14.2-1.el7`. In EPEL there is a newer version, but I can't use it. If I find an RPM package of cairo and try to install it, it fails because there are dependencies that it needs and they are also not found in EPEL.

Which repos can I add to install older versions of packages? Are there any popular choice to look at first?

Comment: I think, it is possible to install specific version of package from epel repository. Read this: https://www.shellhacks.com/yum-install-specific-version-of-package/

Comment: `cairo-1.14.2-1.el7` http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/cairo-1.14.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm ... All "1611" packages http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/ ... All old CentOS (7) packages http://vault.centos.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @KnudLarsen, here is the repo that I added to my `/etc/yum.repos.d`:

```
[centos-old.rep]
name=centos-old
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Which allowed me to install older versions.